# CSS Gradient Background is being weird

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am currently having issues with CSS it does this weird repeating thing even though when I worked on it, it was fine before. Then I started tweaking it and now it's just constantly repeating this is the code I did below.

```css
body {
 background-image: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}
```

This is what turns up when you go to the webpage.

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set height to your html and body so that it doesnt just wrap your existing elements

```
html, body { height: 100% }
```

try adding this

Comment: It did work, but now I am stuck with the scrollbar and now has this bracket shape gradient issue.

Comment: i dont understand your problem now.

Comment: maybe your body tag is missing `margin` and `padding` set to 0?

Comment: @Syfer that actually fixed that scrolling issue thanks for helping, both of you.

Comment: body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
works correctly!